# Independent functions and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\varphi_1 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $\varphi_2 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be two linearly independent functions. Consider the following argument:

> Since the matrix
> $$
> A=
> \frac{1}{2}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1
> \\
> -i & i
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> is invertible,
> the functions
> $$
> \psi_1 = \frac{1}{2}( \varphi_1 + \varphi_2 )
> \\
> \psi_2 = \frac{1}{2i}(\varphi_1 - \varphi_2)
> $$
> are linearly independent.

One can see that
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1
\\
1/i & -1/i
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\varphi_1
\\
\varphi_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1
\\
\psi_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the matrix above is the same as $A$, since $1/i=-i$, $-1/i=i$.

What result is applied from linear algebra which links the invertibility of the matrix $A$ and the independence of $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$?

Comment: $1/i=-i, -1/i=i.$ The matrix is not different.

Comment: $\frac1i = \frac1i \frac i i = \frac i{-1}=-i$

Comment: $(\varphi_1, \varphi_2)$ is a basis of the two dimensional real space spanned by themselves. Since a vector space is isomorphic to any vector space of the same dimension (with the same scalars) you can identity $\varphi_1$ with $e_1$ and $\varphi_2$ with $e_2$ and use regular linear algebra on $\mathbb R^2$. Hope this helps. Edit: changed the phis to varphis

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac1i=-i, -\frac1i=i$, hence
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1
\\
1/i & -1/i
\end{pmatrix}=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1
\\
-i& i
\end{pmatrix}=A
$$